# How to assert multiple properties in System Verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

What is the most efficient way to assert multiple properties in SV ?

Example:

```
property x;
   if(expr1)
       a===b;
endproperty

property y;
   if(expr2)
       c===d;
endproperty
```

Is something like this is needed: `assert (x && y)`?

Comment: Hi @ECEVLSI, can you please explain what you are trying to do in property x? Are you checking if a is logically equivalent to b whenever expr1 is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the property `and` operator

```
assert (x and y);
```

For your example, there's not much difference from the logical `&&` operator, but that operator can only be used on Boolean expressions.